# How to parse yyyymm data format to Month, YYYY format in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, simpledateformat

I have a string value which is equal to `"202004"`. how can I convert it to `"April, 2020"`  in Java?

Comment: a simple substring and a conditional statement will be able to help you out there

Comment: Create two `DateTimeFormatter`s (one for parsing the input and the other one for formatting the desired output) and use then in connection with a `java.time.YearMonth`.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to `April, 2020`? What will you use the string for? Output to JSON, show on a Thymeleaf web page, print to console, something else?

Comment: You tagged your question simpledateformat, but I recommend that you never use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) as also shown in the very good answer by deHaar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `java.time` for a task like this.

You can define two `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` instances (one for parsing the input string to [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) and another for formatting the obtained `YearMonth` to a string of the desired format).

Define a method like this one:

```java
public static String convert(String monthInSomeYear, Locale locale) {
    // create something that is able to parse such input
    DateTimeFormatter inputParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMM");
    // then use that formatter in order to create an object of year and month
    YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(monthInSomeYear, inputParser);
    /*
     * the output format is different, so create another formatter
     * with a different pattern. Please note that you need a Locale
     * in order to define the language used for month names in the output.
     */
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                            "MMMM, uuuu",
                                            Locale.ENGLISH
                                        );
    // then return the desired format
    return yearMonth.format(outputFormatter);
}
```

then use it, e.g. in a `main` method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your example input
    String monthInAYear = "202004";
    // use the method
    String sameMonthInAYear = convert(monthInAYear, Locale.ENGLISH);
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(sameMonthInAYear);
}
```

The output will be this:

```
April, 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below one line code to format year month

```
int yearMonth = Integer.parseInt("202004"); 
String yearMonthStr = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[(yearMonth % 10)-1] + ", "+yearMonth/100;
System.out.println(yearMonthStr);
```

Comment: Your code is not correct. I tried with `201912` for February 2019, but your code printed `februar, 2019`. I recommend against doing your own date math, it’s way too easy to get wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Use DateFormatSymbols() class to implement the new date format from the string

```
 String text="202011";
        int num=0;
        //Checking the last second character of the text for jan to sept month
        if(text.charAt(text.length()-2)==0){
            num=Integer.parseInt(""+text.charAt(text.length()-1))-1;
        }
        else {
            num=Integer.parseInt(""+text.substring(text.length()-2))-1;
        }
        //Checking correct month value
        if(num>=0&&num<=11){
        
        String month = "";
       
        DateFormatSymbols date_ = new DateFormatSymbols();
        String[] month_name = date_.getMonths();
        month = month_name[num];
       
        System.out.println(month+","+text.substring(0,4));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Wrong month value");
    }
```

Comment: Well, even though a simple and straightforward solution exists (see the answer by deHaar), you may of course take the long and complicated way. While you may be happy with it, I’m convinced that the people maintaining your code after you will not be.

Answer (score -1):

```java
SimpleDateFormat oldFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, yyyy");
Date date = null;
    try {
        date = oldFormat.parse("202004");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
String newDateString = newFormat.format(date);
```

[SimpleDateFormat documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score -1):

Let try my code snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat inSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
Date date = inSdf.parse("202112");
        
SimpleDateFormat outSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, yyyy");
String sDate = outSdf.format(date);
System.out.println(sDate);
```

Result:

```
December, 2021
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.